# cytoscape.js: selected nodes are fixed in arbor layout

Tags: cytoscape.js, arbor.js

I render a small graph using cytoscape.js 2.2.4 and the arbor layout.

When I do the layout a second time with one or more nodes selected, the selected ones are fixed and do not move.

You can see what I mean in [the Arbor section of the cytoscape.js docs](http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/#layouts/arbor):

- click 'Run code' to apply the arbor layout to the example graph once
- select a node and click 'Run code' again, the selected node is fixed and does not move

I checked with `cy.nodes(":locked")` for locked nodes but the selection is not locked. Arbor.js [has a 'fixed' property for nodes](http://arborjs.org/reference), but I can't see where cytoscape.js sets this property.

Is it possible to have the seleted node move when applying the arbor layout? Can I pass the `fixed: false` node property to arbor.js?

I use this to add something to the graph when clicking a node. I add some more nodes/edges and start the layout again. If the clicked node is fixed, the layout is messed up.

---

**Update 1**

I figured out that it isn't effected by the `locked` state of the node but rather `grabbable`. When I run `cy.nodes().ungrabify()` just before the layout, the clicked node is not fixed.

When I do `cy.nodes().grabify()` in the stop callback of the layout or with a long `setTimeout()` after the layout, the nodes become grabbable again.

**But** when I then click another node and start the layout again, the node stays grabbed (as in `console.log(cy.nodes(":grabbed"))`) even though `cy.nodes().ungrabify()` is called.

This looks like the grabbable/ungrabbable properties are overridden somewhere. [Cytoscape.js itself uses](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/master/src/extensions/layout.arbor.js#L260) `ungrabify()` and `grabify()` within the arbor layout function, but this doesn't have an effect.

How can I `ungrabify()` and `grabify()` the nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've encountered a renderer bug: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/528

Should just make it into 2.2.5.

Comment: Perfect! So far the workaround was to make nodes grabbable only after 'select'. That seemed to work.